# Where in the ECMAScript specification can I find the reason about why {} !== {}?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

In JavaScript We all know that `{} !== {}` - they are different objects allocated on heap. But I was trying to find the reason at the language specification level.

at https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-samevaluenonnumeric it says

> 7. If x and y are the same Object value, return true. Otherwise, return false.

But it is unclear to me how the spec defines exactly when two objects are considered to have the same Object value. Like `{}` and `{}` clearly do not have the same value but how exactly is it defined in the spec?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#comparing_objects

Comment: @HyunjuneKim That explains *what*, which I'm sure OP is aware of, but not *how* that behavior follows from the spec text

Comment: Maybe 20.1.1: "The Object constructor: [...] creates a new ordinary object when called as a constructor." I'm pretty sure the behavior you're asking about is implied through the interaction of several rules rather implicitly specified.

Comment: I can't find anything specifically referring to this after a cursory glance and searching for a few keywords. It could be that "the same Object value" should be interpreted as "the same Object" (since both objects being compared are "ECMAScript Language Values")

Comment: @CertainPerformance yea I don't really need MDN link. I am very familiar with equality check in JavaScript but I was just having a hard time finding where exactly  the spec defines that equality check for objects.

Comment: The spec is fairly hard to read. It is not written from the point of view of the language's behavior. Instead it is written from the point of view of how to write a javascript interpreter in another language (eg. C++ or go or Java). You won't really find things like `equality operator works like this` instead you will find `when you encounter the equality operator these are the steps you do to process it`

Comment: ... which means you won't find examples of what things compare to what things in the spec - those things are "documented" in blogs and places like MDN. In the spec you will need to apply the code you need to write to implement equality operator to the code that you need to write to implement object literals - both of which are in different parts of the spec.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find that specified the relevant information in the specification document. And the content of "===" continues from the description of "Numerical Types". I think we should follow the explanation of the in [13.11. equality operators](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-equality-operators)

Comment: In ES6 the part of the spec for `===` is 7.2.13. Specifically step number 8 - if x and y are the same **Object value** return true, followed by step 9 - return false. I can't find what the definition of "Object value" is but I suspect it resolves to an instance of an object. So two different object literals are different object values.

Comment: This seems largely a discussion around semantics - from the way the specification is written, 'Object value' simply means a value of the type Object, which means a reference to a specific object, as that's what the value of an Object type variable *is*. You wouldn't have these questions around 'integer value' either, it would be clear that 'same integer value' means 'containing the same value of type integer'. 'Containing the same value of type Object' reasonably means 'referring to the same object', not 'containing references to objects that have identical values for all their properties'

Answer (score 2):

`{}` in this context is an [ObjectLiteral](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#prod-ObjectLiteral), when the [runtime evaluation encounters such an ObjectLiteral](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-evaluation) it calls [OrdinaryObjectCreate](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#sec-ordinaryobjectcreate) which itself calls [MakeBasicObject](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-makebasicobject) which does return a **new** object.

So two ObjectLiterals can't be SameObject.

Comment: hmm but it doesn't explicitly say that instances returned by `MakeBasicObject` cannot be equal right? or considered the same value.

Comment: Yes it does, it says "Let obj be a newly created object". Two "newly created object[s]" can't be the "same" object.

Comment: When two records reference the same object one of them didn't create it but instead used it directly.
For instance the [`Object(object)`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-object-value) call [returns `argument`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-toobject), so it does not create a new object.

Comment: what is a record? it is a The Reference Record Specification Type?

Comment: In this case it would be a [Completion Record](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-completion-record-specification-type) since [runtime semantics "always return a completion record"](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics), but I doubt it really matters what kind of Record it is.